# Does the same-origin policy count for CSS styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am working with a booking system which handles our sites bookings from our customers. When a customer checks room availability, it is done on the booking site, (redirected) not on our site.

My question is: with regards to the same-origin policy, does it count for css styling? Am I allowed to change the background color to match that of ours inside an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with *same-origin policy* - Applying a CSS file to an iFrame is possible, though not recommeded. You can create a `link` element to refer to your CSS file and set it inside your iFrame:

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "http://example/css/style.css";  // Your CSS URL
link.rel = "stylesheet";  
link.type = "text/css";  
frames['frame1'].document.body.appendChild(link);
```

This code "pushes" the iFrame's HTML with a link to your CSS file.

**Note**: If your iFrame's HTML source existing CSS rules have overriding styles (for example, set with `!important`), your CSS values may be overruled.